# How to not truncate INFO messages in bazel output?

Tags: bazel

The INFO: messages emitted when running bazel are truncated to size of the terminal.
How can I specify bazel not to truncate INFO messages?

When I redirect the output to a file - of course it has the complete info.

When I change the terminal size manually, it truncates to the terminal size. The options to set the terminal size ex: `export COLUMNS=500` or `stty rows 50 cols 132` doesn't seem to work.

Either way I need a bazel option and not looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to `bazel .... |& tee /dev/null`

Comment: Bazel has a hidden flag `--terminal_columns`, which might work. It's hidden because it's really only used for the bazel client to tell the bazel server how wide the terminal is

Comment: "--terminal_columns 0" does the job.